# In C # how to change a value in a JObject, having the token in string format?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Let me explain with a simple example, I have a JObject that would have a structure like this:

```
{"Age": 23, "Id": "123", "Name": "Jose"}
```

I have a token of type string which is:

```
"Age"
```

And I have an object type int of value:

```
40
```

How can I update the Age value in the JObject to be 40 and not 23?

Answer (score 1):

```
JObject jobj = JObject.Parse("{'Age': 23, 'Id': '123', 'Name': 'Jose'}");
jobj["Age"] = 40
```